# What is this object in this photo?

Tags: star, planet, the-moon, space

[image]

i took it and i don't know what planet or star is this and also there's our moon

Comment: Almost impossible to tell unless you provide exact time, date and location! It could even be a smudge / mark on the camera sensor!

Comment: Roblox, you may have noticed that your questions are being downvoted and closed.   Please step back, read the posting guidelines, and read a bunch of upvoted questions to get a feel for what constitutes a worthwhile question

Comment: For me it's easy to guess but please consider the comment  Be aware that free planetarium like applications exist for future observations

Answer (score 10):

Almost certainly Jupiter, if the following are true:

- The title of the image: Inked20190904_194204.LI.jpg gives the
  accurate date and time of September 4 2019, 19:42:04.
- The orientation of the Moon in the image is such that the
  illuminated portion is on the right side of the image.
- The circled object is a planet or star, and brighter than any
  other nearby object to the moon at the stated time, and is roughly
  20° away from the Moon.

[image: Stellarium Screenshot from roughly the stated time.]

The Moon moves roughly 13° across the sky every 24 hours, so it's pretty close to the same region as  the screenshot, assuming the local times are accurate.  Jupiter's at apparent magnitude -1.78 in my screenshot, and the next brightest nearby object is to the moon the star Antares, which at magnitude +1.05, is significantly dimmer. Venus is brighter, of course, but at 7:45 PM on the stated date, it's sitting very close to the horizon, if it hasn't already set. Saturn would also be up at the time, but it's about 50° away from the Moon, and dimmer than Jupiter.

Comment: Insane detective work, great job. Would've NEVER noticed that timestamp.